# Spring web application. Can't Run on Server -> 404 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

Here is the problem. I have a Spring web application which I develop on two computers: one with Windows another in Linux, and I share the code via github.

So far I did not have any problems until recently. I can't run in on linux. I get 404 error. At the same time it's working perfectly fine on Windows. I even managed to run it on a completely different computer (fitted with Windows).

Both laptops were switched to Java 8 and that was my primary suspect but so far I couldn't find anything that would cause this issue..

I would appreciate if somebody pointed me the way to fix it.

Comment: Have you checked server logs?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: go to this directory , `$TOMCAT_HOME/logs/` and search for catalina.out

Comment: @Ivan
This is what i found:
**0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [23/Nov/2015:07:27:41 +0100] "GET /MojeWww/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 1086**

Comment: Also this:
23-Nov-2015 07:28:15.005 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
23-Nov-2015 07:28:15.110 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]  
(and so on...)